# The latest version of breakpad without C++11

Tags: c++11

My Linux compiler version is gcc 4.4.7, it doesn't support C++11, but breakpad need compiler supporting c++11, which breakpad version is the latest without C++11??

Comment: Why not update your compiler?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox  The client's machine cannot be upgraded....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,you need this:[Google breakpad On Github](https://github.com/google/breakpad)，[GCC 8.2.0 download](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-8.2.0/).